# NoRM -> To use or not to use?

Tags: .net, mongodb, norm

I'm going to start learning MongoDB using the latest available .NET drivers.

However I know about this cool-looking project:
http://normproject.org/

Is it really worse to use it? (it was updated 1 year ago)

Are there any other best-practices or any cool helper frameworks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NoRM was a great project with some really talented developers behind it.  However, as you said, it hasn't been updated in a long time and is a dead project.  The mongodb database innovates pretty rapidly and the NoRM driver does not support many of the features of the database.

The official C# driver is definitely the way to go.  There is a lot of helpful documentation here: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Language+Center.  In addition, you can pull in the 10gen driver using nuget.